# Raw tcp send and recv

Tags: tcp, ip

I'm making an application, using raw sockets and need your advice:

The application is a tester of some kind of tcp/ip stack.
What I need I have an application that connects with a remote server and transmits some data to id.
lets say - I cannot open sockets from my application  - all I have is tcp/Ip buffer with all headers and so on.

For testing I wanna make 2 raw sockets - 1 for sending and 1 for receiving ip buffers.

for receiving i have this code:

```
int saddr_size , data_size;
struct sockaddr saddr;


unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(65536); //Its Big!

printf("Starting...\n");
//Create a raw socket that shall sniff
sock_raw = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW , IPPROTO_TCP);
if(sock_raw < 0)
{
    printf("Socket Error\n");
    return 1;
}
while(1)
{
    saddr_size = sizeof saddr;
    //Receive a packet
    data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , 65536 , 0 , &saddr , &saddr_size);
    if(data_size <0 )
    {
        printf("Recvfrom error , failed to get packets\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Data size = %d", data_size);

}
close(sock_raw);
printf("Finished");
return 0;
```

And as I can see it works - it gets all TCP/IP packets.

For sender I tryed this

```
  static const unsigned char pkt6[60] = {
0x32, 0x04, 0x34, 0xed, 0xf3, 0xab, 0x01, 0x02, /* 2.4..... */
0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x08, 0x00, 0x45, 0x00, /* ......E. */
0x00, 0x2e, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0x06, /* ........ */
0x44, 0xc5, 0xc0, 0xa8, 0x01, 0x02, 0xac, 0x11, /* D....... */
0x09, 0x47, 0x00, 0x08, 0x1a, 0x0b, 0x00, 0x00, /* .G...... */
0x19, 0x6e, 0x23, 0x17, 0xc8, 0x36, 0x50, 0x18, /* .n#..6P. */
0x08, 0x60, 0x2b, 0xb9, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6c, 0x6f, /* .`+...lo */
0x6f, 0x6c, 0x0a, 0x00                          /* ol.. */
};

if((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0) {
 perror("error:");
 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }


while(1) {
  if(send(s, pkt6, sizeof(pkt6), 0)< 0)
      perror("error::");
 }
   }
```

And it always says

```
error:: Destination address required
```

So what do I need to change if i want to send READy IP packets and get raw ip packets?

Answer (score 0):

I've not use raw sockets this way myself, but AIUI you'll probably need to use `sendto()` instead of `send()`, and pass the `saddr` structure that you obtained in the `recvfrom()` call.

Comment: sendto neds IP address. And I have READY IP packet with all headers and so on. I just need to pass it to the network. May be I can just write it to socket fd?

Comment: the `saddr` structure doesn't necessarily contain IP addresses.  What's in the one you're getting out of `recvfrom` ?

Comment: Recv part works great. I need to send to network ready IP packet. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm talking about the TX part!  Every example I can find uses `sendto()` with a `struct sockaddr` representing the destination.  You also have to consider the `IP_HDRINCL` socket option to tell the kernel _not_ to generate an IP header of its own.

Comment: How can I do that? Can you give sample code please?